# Compartilhar a mesma Sessão em Dominios Diferentes no mesmo Servidor

Tags: php, session

É possível compartilhar a mesma sessão entre domínios diferentes no mesmo servidor?

Caso seja possível, o que fazer para obter tal façanha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexandre, realmente esta façanha não é possível, a sessão permanece ativa somente no domínio que a criou, no máximo o que poderia ser feito seria compartilhar esta sessão para utilização nos subdomínios do domínio em questão.

Answer (score 1):

## Sim, é possível

Mas envolve um tanto de código, e solução não é tão simples. Dois problemas separados a resolver: permitir que os dados de sessão estejam acessíveis à "servidores" diferentes, que o ID de sessão alcance as dois domínios diferentes.

#### Compartilhar os dados de sessão

Os dados de sessão do PHP normalmente ficam guardados como arquivos num diretório temporário específico. Ver [session_save_path()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-save-path.php). Caso ambas as aplicações esteja, no mesmo servidor fisicamente, uma solução é criar uma pasta compartilhada e chamar `session_save_path()` antes de `session_start()`.

Nem sempre é possível. Servidores em esquema de domínios virtuais geralmente proíbem o acesso a arquivos fora do DocRoot configurado, de forma que uma pasta comum é impossível.

Solução alternativa é usar um [manipulador personalizado](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.customhandler.php) para ler/gravar os dados de sessão num banco de dados ou um [memcached](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/memcached.sessions.php) da vida, fugindo assim das restrições de DocRoot.

#### Compartilhar o ID de sessão

Ainda é preciso que ambas aplicações recebam o mesmo *session ID*. IDs de sessão do PHP podem [ser passados por cookies ou URL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.idpassing.php). Cookies ficam restritos ao domínio onde eles foram criados, e não podem ser criados "para outros domínios".

O jeito é fazer que *ambos* os domínios registrarem o *mesmo cookie, ao mesmo tempo*. Algo assim:

```
<img src="http://www.dominio1.com/cross_session.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>"/>
<img src="http://www.dominio2.com/cross_session.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>"/>
```

E no arquivo `cross_session.php` simplesmente chama `session_start()` passando o SID como argumento. Isso vai criar o cookie apropriado, e quando o cara pular de um site para outro, a sessão estará esperando por ele, de forma transparente.

#### Caveat emptor

O código acima é um exemplo mínimo. Funciona, mas é feio. Deixa rastro dos IDs de sessão em logs de servidor.

Solução menos feiosa seria fazer via JavaScript/Ajax requisições tipo POST  (para não deixar rastro) em nomes de arquivos menos óbvios (para deixar o pessoal incitado a futucar seu servidor).

O importante é que um navegador tenha a o SID de forma explícita, e que esse um navegador faça requisições nos dois domínios, para assim criar dois cookies, um para cada domínio, com o mesmo SID. A página seguinte ao login é ideal para fazer isso.