# Compartilhar Sessões com diferentes dominios em servidores diferentes

Tags: php, session

estou com um probleminha. Nós possuímos 3 sites o site1.com o site2.com e o site3.com. O site um é nosso site mestre onde cadastramos os usuários e onde os mesmos fazem login. Nós utilizamos a SESSION para realizar o 'LOGIN'. Nosso problema é logar o mesmo usuário nos site2 e site3 assim que ele loga no site1. O queremos é algo parecido com o esquema do Google ou Microsoft em que você loga em um site principal e automaticamente ele loga nos outros serviços.

```
//Aqui crio a sessão.
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
 $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
 $_SESSION['useremail'] = $row['email'];

//Verifica a sessão
if(!isset($_SESSION['useremail'])){
//Não está logado

}else
{
 //Está logado

}
```

O Problema e que quando vamos recuperar a SESSION nos sites 2 e 3 não recupera, estudamos e vimos que era em razão dos cookies do servidor ficarem no servidor 1 e por isso não vai. Também andei pesquisando sobre o assunto e encontrei algumas soluções, porém era para sites de mesmo servidor. Vocês podem nos ajudar ? Enviar um POST para um arquivo em cada site para setar a sessão é perigoso ou temos que usar o DB para fazer esse controle? Como podemos fazer isso ? Desde já agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: tem uma pergunta igual em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92702/compartilhar-a-mesma-sess%c3%a3o-em-dominios-diferentes-no-mesmo-servidor

Comment: O que você quer é fazer um SSO (Single Sign On), deve ter postagem sobre isso aqui no StackOverflow.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo então o que devo fazer no ato do login e registrar em todos os sites uma sessão com o mesmo ID da sessão que se fez no site 1? Se for isso não ficaria arriscado, tipo facilitando para alguém roubar a sessão ? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Patrick A Lima eu não sei, só te indiquei um link que talvez pudesse te dar uma luz. Mas reparando bem lá é no mesmo servidor então nada feito.

Comment: kkkkkk. Sim é no mesmo servidor. Nosso sites estão em servidores diferentes. Basicamente o que precisamos é isso logar no site1 e automaticamente logar no 2 e 3. Igual o sistema do Google ou a Microsoft. Andei pensando em fazer um POST p/ cada site com a ID da Session p/ fazer ele cadastrar nos sites a mesma sessão, teoricamente isso poderia dar certo, mais não sei se é correto/Seguro fazer isso.

Comment: A maneira mais simples de fazer isso envolveria passar o ID da sessão como um parâmetro GET de uma página em um domínio para uma página no outro domínio. Em seguida, no outro domínio, você pegaria o ID da sessão e criaria uma nova sessão usando esse ID. Embora essa seja uma maneira simples de fazê-lo, não é muito seguro e permite o seqüestro de sessão.

Comment: Uma maneira melhor seria usar o banco de dados para criar um registro com o id de sessão nele, definir um curto tempo limite sobre ele e passar o ID desse registro para o outro domínio. O outro domínio, em seguida, pegar o registro do banco de dados e criar uma sessão com ele. Se o registro no banco de dados tiver passado sua expiração, ele não pegaria a sessão. Isso proporcionaria melhor proteção contra seqüestro de sessão

Comment: Obs: Já te adiantei a tradução desse post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759312/session-share-across-multiple-domains-on-same-server

Comment: kkkkk Ah sim. Então só duas coisa, sobre isso que você falou do banco de dados de cadastrar lá, como eu faria p/ o site 2 e 3 saberem que a pessoa já logou no 1. Eu precisaria de um POST p/ isso como eu poderia fazer? Dois sobre o Banco essa técnica poderia torna-lo lento ou não influencia

Comment: kkk, isso tem que perguntar lá no posto ypiranga, ou seja, no link que te passei. Vou perguntar lá.

Comment: Ah ok. Vou ver lá. Obrigado desde já pela ajuda

Comment: Não deu, tem q se registrar lá tb. ;)

Comment: Acabei de entrar mais diz que não tenho pontos suficientes kkkk que coisa eh

Comment: te dei mais uns pontos na sua pergunta

Comment: kkk Obrigado mais não vai dar. O Stackoverflow está separando meu perfil daqui para o site em inglês. Então lá eu tenho zero pontos e não posso comentar, diz que preciso de 50 pontos.

Comment: vc consegue de um servidor acessar um banco de outro servidor?

Comment: Sim consigo, já fiz este teste.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56120/discussion-between-leo-caracciolo-and-patrick-a-lima).